# why jquery UI Widgets doesn't work in my laravel application?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui

I have laravel application and trying to use dialog widget, but I keep getting this error in the console:

> TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function[Learn More]

I tried to test normal jquery functions and it works fine, it is just jquery UI.

```
    <head>

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( ".opener" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
    } );
   </script>
     </head>


    <body>
     <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information.   The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
     </div>
```

**Update:**

there is a conflict between these lines:

```
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

but still can't remove any of them.

**Update 2**

> webpack.mix.js

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

> app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

> bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Comment: On exactly which line do you get this error?

Comment: $( "#dialog" ).dialog({

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem with your current supplied code

Comment: let me ask you something, does app.js application loads a copy of the jquery ui or something, maybe it is a conflict between two copies

Comment: You you tried looking at the full page output? Use your browsers inspect function to see all loaded js files

Comment: I removed this line,     <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
 and it worked but , I still need the app.js because it is a part of laravel application

Comment: Show your laravel mix file

Comment: please find the question update 2. I placed the webpack.mix.js contents and other related files contents too. might it help you to help me :)

Answer (score 2):

See this link: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/jquery-ui.md

**NOTE:** I am fairly new to Laravel Mix (webpack) and still learning.

In the linked example his **resources/assets/js/app.js** contains the lines:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

but in my case I'm editing **resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js**, which contains the line:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

so I added the widget import line:

```
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/dialog.js';
```

After the edits, to run the Mix tasks, I ran this command at my project root: **npm run dev**

And in my Chrome browser, on the page calling $(...).dialog(), I opened the devtools console and then right clicked on the browser page reload icon and clicked **Empty cache and hard reload**

Since I am using Laravel Mix (webpack) I do not need to include the jquery specific script tags and stylesheet links.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the .sass file that you're mixing in your webpack.mix.js file?

If not, try changing your webpack.mix.js to this:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

New to Laravel and web development in general; that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting app.js before jquery-ui.js. This makes jquery-ui.js overwrite any common code. I found it does not cause significant side-effects. Some items like tooltips will look different, but you can just modify the linked js files to handle that if necessary.